# Order by rand(). Put first row in the end

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is this possible somehow?:

Select all rows ( order by rand() )

Make a while loop that outputs all rows *except the first one*

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM tablename ORDER BY rand ()';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {

   // IF NOT FIRST ROW, DO THIS
   $text .= '<p>' . $row['id'] . '<br />' . $row['name'] . '</p>';

}
```

And then include the excluded row at end

```
$text .= '<p>' . $FIRSTROW_id . '<br />' . $FIRSTROW_name . '</p>';
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Randomising the results will make putting the first result last meaningless, your first row isn't going to be distinguishable from the last row anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If the ordering is random, then any row can be first, so you are not effectively doing anything.  If there is a *particular* row you want first, then that can easily be accomplished.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a big difference between "The first one" selected randomly and "The last one", but you could write "The first one" to a different variable (ie not `$text`) and then append it after you're done looping.

Comment: The plan is to set the main content (one row), then make an array for jquery/ajax (for a continuous slider). And that array should not start with the first row (to avoid repeating same content). Hope you understand

Comment: @mowgli so you want "infinite scrolling" with randomly sorted rows?

Answer (score 0):

Create a count and if it's first value, save it in variable.
Then, after loop, you use your variable with data from first row.

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM tablename ORDER BY rand ()';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

$i = 0;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ( $i == 0 )
        $firstrow = $row;
    else
        $text .= '<p>' . $row['id'] . '<br />' . $row['name'] . '</p>';

    $i++;
}

if ( $firstrow )
    $text .= '<p>' . $firstrow['id'] . '<br />' . $firstrow['name'] . '</p>';
```

---

EDIT : From what you said in comments, you can just pass first row as param in AJAX and exclude it in your query :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM tablename WHERE id != '".intval($_GET['id'])."' ORDER BY rand ()";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
```

`$_GET['id']` will be param you send by AJAX.

Comment: I tried this, and other ways.. I realize I simply have to check with js/jquery which id is current in the div. And then now switch to same content id